# Angular class that uses service creates circular dependency

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

I have a menu service which holds menu structure by using menu classes. The menu classes uses menuItem classes.

The Service does some http requests to get data. From this data menu classes are created. The following code is strongly simplified.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"

import { Menu } from "../classes/menu";
import { MenuItem } from "../classes/menuItem";
import { menusResponseInterface } from "../interfaces/menusResponse";
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Injectable()
export class MenusService {
  private menus;
  private getMenuesObservers$;
  private getMenuesObserver;
  private getMenusStateObservers$;
  private getMenusStateObserver;
  private urls;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private data: DataService,
    private config: ConfigService
  ) {
    this.getMenuesObservers$ = [];
    this.menus = [];
    this.urls = {};
    this.init();
  }

  init(){
    this.getMenuesObserver = new Observable(observer => {
      this.getMenuesObservers$.push(observer);
    });
    this.getMenusStateObserver = new Observable(observer => {
      this.getMenusStateObservers$ = observer;
    });

    this.http.get(`${this.config.baseURL}/api/getMenues`).subscribe((response:menusResponseInterface) => {
      var index;

      for( index in response.menus){
        this.menus[index] = new Menu(response.menus[index]);
        this.menus[index].setMenuItems(response.pages[index]);
      }

      for( var i = 0; i< this.getMenuesObservers$.length; i++){
        this.getMenuesObservers$[i].next(this.menus);
      }
    });
  }

  public getMenues(){
    return this.getMenuesObserver;
  }


  public function getMenuItemByUrl:MenuItem(url:string){

  }

}
```

The Menu Class creates a tree structure of MenuItems.

```
import { MenuItem } from "./menuItem";
export class Menu {
    public setMenuItems(menuItems){
        // loop data and create treeStructure of MenuItems
        menuItem = new MenuItem(menuItems);

        .
        .
        .

        menuItem.children.push(childMenuItem);
    }    
}
```

The MenuItem class holds data about parent, childs, name and url. The url is created by asking all parents about there name plus the own name. I want to inject again the MenuService into the MenuItem class, so I can send all url to it. I want to have all URLs in MenuService so I can match it against the router url,

```
import { MenusService } from '../services/menus.service';
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';

export class MenuItem {
   public id:number;
   public name:string;
   private url:string;
   .
   .
   .

   public children:Array<MenuItem>;
   public parent:MenuItem;

   private menuService:MenusService

   constructor(
       data
   ){
       let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([MenusService]);
       this.menuService = injector.get(MenusService);
   }
   
   .
   .
   .

   public getUrl(){
       if(typeof(this.url) == "undefined"){
           if(typeof(this.parent) == "undefined" || this.parent.id == 0){
               this.url = encodeURI(this.name.replace(new RegExp(/ / , 'g'), '-'));
           }
           else{
               this.url = this.parent.getUrl()+'/'+encodeURI(this.name.replace(new RegExp(/ / , 'g'), '-'));
           }
           this.menuService.registerURL(this.url, this);
       }
       return this.url;
    }
}
```

This would work nicely if it would not create a circular dependency.
MenuService uses Menu which uses MenuItem which uses MenuService. After injecting MenuService into MenuItem Class I get circular dependency warnings and the app breaks.

Is there a Angular way to solve this without this circular dependency problem?

Comment: Don't resolve the dependency in the constructor, but when you actually need it ?

Comment: See getURL function. When the first time called getUrl its generated and sent to MenuService.

Comment: If you move `this.menuService = injector.get(MenusService);` from constructor to `getUrl` ?

Comment: Same problem. CLI gives circular dependency warnings. I can compile but app breakes, because the provider for HttpClient can not be found anymore in MenuService.

Comment: and if you don't call `init` in the `MenuService` constructor, but later? It's a bit hard to say without seeing where the http calls are

Comment: I'd look into trying to separate concerns better so that neither Menu or MenuItem needs to know about the service. You could do all the logic in the service?

Comment: But if you must do it this way, add a Subject as a MenuItem property (static perhaps), subscribe to it in the service, communicate that way back to the service.

Comment: added hole MenuService code to make it clearer.
It would be hard to do all the logik in the Service without classes. Never worked with Subjects. Going to learn about them..

Comment: Btw. it doesn't matter where you call Injector.get or if you even don't. As long as there's import B from 'B' in A, and import A from A in B, that's a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pointers elaborating on my comment about using Subject for communicating back to the service:

```
// MenuItem.ts
static registerUrl:Subject<MenuItem> = new Subject();
// instead of service.registerUrl():
MenuItem.registerUrl.next(this)

// service onInit
MenuItem.registerUrl.subscribe(item => {
    // do stuff with item.url
});
```

Voila, MenuItem doesn't need to import the service.